# Frequency check time

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to have a frequency check time to my website and when the time is 20:00-21:00 to display a streaming channel else it will display an image. I've tried to do it with php but it was wrong way because the website would have looped unstoppable.

UPDATED

I want also to do this every 30sec.

PHP

```
<?php
while(1){
    $now = date('G',time());
    $start = 20;
    $end = 21;
    if($now >= $start && $now <= $end){ 
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("liveTV_api").style.display="block"; document.getElementById("adtv").style.display="none";</script>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("adtv").style.display="block"; document.getElementById("liveTV_api").style.display="none";</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please share the code that you've already tried.

Comment: Doing it in JS (only) is also the wrong way because you can't know what time the client has. Show the PHP code, perhaps someone can advice how to fix it.

Comment: @Juhana I don't want to do this in client's time. I want a standard time to me. Because the streaming channel doesn't streams in client's time but in its programming time.

Comment: Yes, and that's why I said JS-only will not work.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, PHP has a limit of 30 seconds (default) on script execution time, after which your script will be aborted, so your given code is highly unlikely to work.

Even if it did, your `while(1)` with no delays in the loop is a terrible resource hog.

Personally, if I wanted to check the time like that, I would use an HTML meta tag to reload the page every second or so `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">` and then check for the time at the start of my PHP, doing nothing until the desired time has arrived.

---

[Update] sorry, I am at work & have no access to PHP / HTML development tools. I can code this correctly in about 12 hours but meanwhile something like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <?php
       if (not currently streaming video)  // coding is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)
       { 
          echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">';
       }
    ?>


  </head>
  <body>
      <?php
    $now = date('G',time());
    $start = 20;
    $end = 21;
    if($now >= $start && $now <= $end){ 
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("liveTV_api").style.display="block"; document.getElementById("adtv").style.display="none";</script>';

       // CodeMe: indicate that the video is streaming (left to you to decide how)

    }
    else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("adtv").style.display="block"; document.getElementById("liveTV_api").style.display="none";</script>';
    }
    ?>  
</body>
```

Comment: It loops again. How could I set it to do check in every 30 sec?

Comment: AArgh - my bad, sorr!! I just hurriedly copied your code and forgot to remvoe the while(1). Please see the update. You can change the update interval in the HTML meta refresh tag by changing the value of "content". Please let me know if this works.

Comment: Hmm when is coming the time for video streaming and page is getting refreshed it's a problem to someone who tries to watch the video.

Comment: I am not sure that I quite understand that. Can you please explain further? (and may upvote, he asked cheekily ;-)

Comment: Someone who wants to watch the video he ll not because of refreshing of the page. It will reload the video every few secs.

Comment: Aha!! A very, very goof point. I have updated the code with pseudo code - basically, you want to use PHP to output a meta refresh tag or blank string depending on whether the video is currently streaming.

Comment: I don't think that it solve the problem. What I want is in specific time to display a streaming video. When this time has passed it will display an image instead of streaming video. Think that this page will have content also. Maybe some text. So, it wouldn't be practical in my opinion.

Comment: Then I don't understand and sorry but I don't think that I can help you more. I copied your own code for comapre time & show video or image and just helped you to page load correctly. I reallz don't see what more I cna do. Sorry